# When was the last American political convention that allowed people to bring guns?

Tags: united-states, constitution, primaries, guns

There is [a petition](http://www.msnbc.com/msnbc/open-carry-the-republican-national-convention) to allow guns at the Republican convention. When was the last political convention (Democrat or Republican) that allowed people to bring guns?

Comment: Depends, what level of convention?

Answer (score 2):

There is no law saying that guns are barred at conventions. The reason they won't be (weren't) allowed is the Secret Service who reserves the right to restrict firearms under Federal Law 18 U.S. Code 3056. I know this doesn't directly answer the question, but it may help re-frame your research. Unless the Secret Service steps in, whether guns are allowed or not will come down to the specific
 city's gun laws.

Comment: When was the Secret Service created?

Comment: 1865 but they were chasing counterfeiters not guarding the president